# Ckeditor and responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, ckeditor

i'm struggling with Ckeditor for a weird behaviour i got when loading some templates.

My template has a part of css with some media queries:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 599px)

{
/* General settings for Mobile */
body{width:auto!important;}
table[class=fullWidth]  {width: 100%!important;}
.....
}

and a part of html, simple table like :

<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"     style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;" >
 <tr>
  <td width="600" height="20" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse:     collapse;"  class="MobileScale2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I paste this code inside the box of Source and, with a pluging made by me, i resize the content area with a simple:

```
$('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').animate({"width": "480px"},400);
```

The weird fact  is: with the Standard Edition of Ckeditor i see that  the layout behaves correctly, changing the width of table from 600 to 100%! when i launch the jquery command,
with the Full edition this does not happens at all...the media query is totally ignored.

This is my config.js file:

```
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2013, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
        // config.language = 'fr';
        // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
  //config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
   config.allowedContent = true;
  //config.allowedContent = 'title img form input param pre flash br a td p span font em strong table tr th td style  script iframe u s li ul div[*]{*}(*)';
   config.startupShowBorders = false;
   config.EnableMoreFontColors = 'true' ;

  config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'mode' },
    { name: 'Image'},
    { name: 'others',groups: [ 'colorpicker']},
    '/',
    { name: 'others'},
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },

    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
    { name: 'styles' }

];


};
```

Anybody can help? I tried to search this problem in google, here and inside the forum of Ckeditor community, but nothing !

Thanks!

---

After hours analysing the code ...i got to fix it.

For some reason The Full version of Ckeditor doesn't understand this syntax:

table[class=fullWidth]

It needs to be changed to:

table.fullWidth

Now it works!

Cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and your solution worked! FYI, you may want to add it as an answer and self-accept rather than simply editing your question.

Comment: Adding `#cke_description { width: auto !important; }` to a stylesheet fixes the issue.